# A* pathfinding algorithm against walls

Tags: java, algorithm, path-finding

So i'm making a game that looks like the following: 
https://gyazo.com/9d72dd5a9ac29f059ed474376f9679a2

Now i'm trying to implement the a* algorithm to get the red tank to the green tank. However looking at existing code, (mainly looking at the pathfinding on cokeandcode.com) they have been implemented using grid based maps.

My game is grid based, however the walls of the maze are made from the edges of each 'square' of the grid, with some walls up and some down to make the maze. The following link may illustrate this better:

https://gyazo.com/afefe7d2bdc2b5f02bf546090459f539

My question is, how would I implement the pathfinding algorithm from the cokeandcode site if my map is not entirely grid based. The algorithm knows if a path is blocked if a square of the grid is not passable, however in my game, all squares are passable. It's the walls of each square that is not passable.

Answer (score 2):

It is still mostly grid based, the difference is that here it's not that tiles are entirely unwalkable, they're just not always connected to all of their 4-neighbourhood.

In terms of A*, that means your "get neighbours"-function is non-trivial and must take walls into account.

For example, you could store 2 bits per cell, one to indicate whether it is connected to the south or not, and one for the east. Then to compute the neighbours of a cell you'd have to ask 3 cells for their bitmaps and it's maybe a bit tricky. You could also store all 4 bits per cell.

If the map is stored as a list of lines, it would be a lot more annoying to compute the neighbours, so I would only suggest that as a storage format, not as an in-memory format.

Comment: Edited question

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

- Make an 8x8 grid of booleans indicating positions of walls in addition to your 7x7 grid of squares (that is, if you need the 7x7 grid for any other reason).
- If you don't already have one, make a `Cell` object that stores any values you need **plus** 4 booleans (probably in an array) indicating whether or not you can travel in each of the 4 directions. Then just make your 7x7 grid of these objects.